# jquery .sortable() on <div> store and retrieve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use sortable() on divs and it's working fine, but I couldn't store the sorted divs and retrieve them for the user in the database.
here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 widget-container-col">
    <div class="widget-box widget-color-blue" id="1">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <h4 class="widget-title">Japanese Yen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="center bold bigger-300"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-jpy smaller-90 up-5"></i> {{ round($currencyWidget['price'], 2) }}</div>
            <div class="center">as of {{ $currencyWidget['date'] }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 widget-container-col">
    <div class="widget-box widget-color-blue" id="2">
        <div class="widget-header">
            <h4 class="widget-title">Another Widget</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="center bold bigger-300">Test Widget</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 widget-container-col">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 widget-container-col">
</div>
```

and Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.widget-container-col').sortable({
    connectWith: '.widget-container-col',
    items: '> .widget-box',
    opacity: 0.8,
    revert: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
    placeholder: 'widget-placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    start: function(event, ui){
        ui.item.parent().css({'min-height': ui.item.height()})
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        ui.item.parent({'min-height':''})
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you,

Comment: You want to store the order of the divs in the DB?

Comment: yes, I need to know, how could I get the sorted data so that I can AJAX it to the database, but how could I get the sorted data in the first place.

Comment: Just loop through the `.widget-container-col` elements and get their ids …?

Comment: You don't have to get the sorted data.  Just get the index position of the elements then store those index values in an array and pass it to the server.  Check out jquery index()

Comment: Could you please show me a sample, or explain more, I am not that good in jquery and jquery ui.

Comment: Also, once I save the data to the database, how would I load the page after retrieving the data from the DB sorted the same way the user stored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the `'id' , 'index'` map of sortable by iterating through all the items in sortable ,

```
$.map($(".widget-container-col > .widget-box "), function(element) {
    return element.id + ' = ' + $(element).index();
});
```

Which will return you data in following form ,

```
["2 = 0", "1 = 1"]
```

#### See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/1283/)

As for this ,

> Also, once I save the data to the database, how would I load the page
>   after retrieving the data from the DB sorted the same way the user
>   stored it.

You should maintain the data in sorted order while fetching from database.